# asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

Tags: python-asyncio, flask-restful, asyncpg

Below is the definition for my get request. The first request returns data successfully. The successive requests error out with error : asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

```
@app.route("/getreportdetails/")
async def data():
    sql = f"select * " \
          f"from get_report_details " 
    report_data = await query(sql)
```

I am connecting to postgres database using asyncpg. Here is the code.

```
pool = None

async def get_pool():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**config.servers.db_credentials)
    return pool

async def query(sql):
    global pool
    print(sql)
    if pool is None:
        pool = await get_pool()
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        async with connection.transaction():
            result = await connection.fetch(sql)
            print(result)
            return result
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?